# Prefetch distance and degree of prefetch

Tags: prefetch

what is the difference between prefetch distance and degree of prefetching?

Comment: Others have already given concise answers. For detailed answer and illustration of prefetch distance and degree, see my [survey paper on cache prefetching techniques](https://www.academia.edu/23625676/A_Survey_of_Recent_Prefetching_Techniques_for_Processor_Caches).

Answer (score 1):

Prefetching typically deals with entire cache lines.  So a given prefetch request will bring in the cache line that would hold the specified address.

Due to the huge differences in memory speeds, it can take many cycles to bring data into the cache.  Some latencies are in the dozens of cycles if not longer.  Now, the only way to really benefit from a prefetch is to issue it far enough ahead of the actual use of the data so that there's enough time for the machine to pull the data into the cache.  This implies that data access be predictable so one can anticipate what memory needs to be in the cache.  The simplest case is marching through a linear array.  Now, a common scenario (in 'scientific code') is a loop that reads the data then processes it.  The cache miss penalty may be high and the processor may be very fast, and simply prefetching the next cache line may not be sufficient as we may be finished processing the array corresponding to the current cache line and waiting for the data in the neighbouring cache line before the data has arrived at the cache.  So we may have to fetch further away than the next cache line.

How far ahead you prefetch is the distance e.g. 512 bytes.  The degree of prefetching is the distance in terms of cache lines i.e. if your cache line is 256 bytes, the degree of prefetching is 2.

Comment: The definition of prefetching degree i'm familiar with is - how many prefetch lines do you issue on each trigger. They don't have to amount to the prefetching distance (which may vary dynamically in some implementations), as long as it gets you there eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Prefetching degree is the number of cache lines to prefetch at each trigger.

Prefetching distance is the concept from array within loop. D = ceil(l / s), l is average memory latency in terms of number of cycles, s is cycle time of shortest execution path. D is be number of iterations ahead for a certain array element, so that memory latency is covered.